# CPU load 100%. vmlinuz, confluence server

Tags: linux, сервер, confluence

вообщем ситуация такая, имееться сервер на DO, где запущен confluence server.
Сегодня был момент что закончилась память на диске, потому сервер не отвечал. Удалил несоклько бекапов, свободной памяти стало на 20-25gb  больше. Перезапустил сервер, и вроде все окей.

Но, через 2 мин он стал снова не отвечать. Я опять зашел на сервак и посмотрел htop.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И эти процесы vmluniz тупо висят и все. Думал надо подождать некоторое время, но нет(

также пытался убить эти процесы, но они снова появлялись.

Я не очень понимаю, что они делают и для чего они, но точно знаю, что мне нужна помощь)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файл ядра в `/boot` называется `vmlinuz` с указанием версии ядра в имени файла. И уж точно он не будет в списке процессов как рядовое приложение.

Вычищайте следы заражения либо переустанавливайте сервер. Затем ставьте обновления.

Вас взломали и скорей всего вы теперь участник ботнета, не исключено что через свежий CVE-2019-3396, [ошибку confluence](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/confluence-security-advisory-2019-03-20-966660264.html) эксплуатируемую без прохождения авторизации.

Уязвимость уже [широко эксплуатируется](https://habr.com/ru/company/pt/blog/447904/).

Comment: А загрузка скорее всего из-за майнинга криптовалюты.